# Why won't my SSD boot when it's cold?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, temperature

I know that some SSDs rarely have an issue with "cold boots" under certain firmware and software configurations. However in this case I have had two SSDs (different brands) that would literally not boot when they were physically cold. If I placed them under my arm until they warmed up to my body temperature, they would boot fine. If I however attempted to boot when they were cold, they would not even appear in the BIOS.

Both SSDs did not develop this issue immediately, the first one did after about 7 months, the second after a couple of years. Both developed it abruptly, there was no slow transition; one day they both just refused to boot cold. I don't see any pattern in the situations. I've changed a lot of my computer between the first one and this one developing this issue (new motherboard, RAM, PSU, etc). About the only hardware thing in common is I might have used the same SATA cable for both, but I can't conceive of any way a cable could do something like this, even if it was shorting (all I can imagine happening is it fries the drive because of an electrical short).

I live in Canada, so we have particularly cold winters. However the computer is in my house and isn't exposed to temperatures my body couldn't withstand. The temperatures are still far above the normal operating temperatures for an SSD, or pretty much any electrical component.

Any ideas? I spent plenty of time researching this issue when it first happened, and did again when it happened with this drive today. All I get is results for drives experiencing "cold boot" issues, none of which have this temperature variable.

Comment: did you even bother trying to research this yourself? cause i just google'd it and got like a zillion hits.

Comment: Did you even bother reading my post? Yes I did plenty of googling. All of those zillion results you're talking about are issues relating to "cold booting" the computer (which refers to physically turning it off and on instead of resetting it), not the SSD refusing to boot when physically cold. Show me one result that is both relevant to my problem and has an answer and I'll happily close the question my self.

Comment: not cold booting, COLD TEMPS. I did read your post.

Comment: Can you safely open the device? $10 says there's a temperature-intermittent connection/solder joint.

Comment: Yes, I can find results for extremely cold operating temperatures, but this computer is in my house, not outside. So we're talking about an ambient temperature of 10 Celsius at the lowest. The house is heated to 19 C most of the time. That should be nowhere near cold enough to cause these issues.

Comment: Are you replying to me? My suggestion stands.

Comment: No I was replying to Sickest. I would open it, but it's still under warranty I believe, which I'm hesitant to void. I did consider a temperature intermittent solder joint, ala XBox 360, but body temperature is far too low to melt solder joints even a little, especially just warming them indirectly through the metal body.

Comment: Not thinking of melting solder, just expanding it a little to reach over a microscopic crack in a joint and close a connection.

Comment: Hmm, it's a possibility, but I'm still skeptical considering cases in which we know that cracked solder joints are the issue are resolved using much higher temperatures than that of the body. Typical solutions are baking the component briefly in an oven (very risky), using a hair dryer on the affected area for an extended period of time, sealing the devices air circulation ports and leaving it powered on for long periods of time (thus forcing an overheat), etc. I'm not completely discarding the idea however.

Comment: Ok, so since I last posted the drive has twice seemingly disconnected from the computer. Being the OS drive it caused the computer to destabilize and crash within 30 seconds or so. I have also realized one common software configuration between the two drives that could be at play here. Both were OS drives encrypted with Truecrypt. They both probably had different versions, but not significantly different. The last drive I got rid of 3 or so years ago. It still sheds no light on why relatively minor temperature variations cause this issue, but it's a start.

Comment: @GetOutOfBox You might want to contact the manufacturer and get them replaced... Also, can you tell us what SSDs are they in particular?  (I'm just wondering if, even though they are different manufacturers, use some of the same hardware internally.)

Answer (score 1):

My SSD has been doing the same for 3 months.  Last night I left my heater next to MY PC set at 65 and pointing at the computer case 1 foot away.  Sure enough the computer booted just fine today, the first time in months that it didn't crash on bootup.  And I have been assuming the SSD was at fault the whole time... Maybe some other component but this PC never had this issue with cold when I had a normal hard drive.  I'm getting a new SSD.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. However only after around 5 years of SSD use. My computer simply did not boot on some cold mornings - afternoons were fine. After several attempts it would magically start up. This correlated with intermittent requests to scan disks on startup. I reseated everything on Motherboard, replaced CMOS battery etc. to no avail. I eventually replaced the SSD and the computer is now magically booting 100% consistently again (hot or cold weather). Just yesterday the same thing happened to a second computer of mine i.e. stopped booting up during cold mornings - a week ago I got a message of disk scan being required. I am on my way today to buy a new SSD - also about 5 years after purchase. I hope this is of help to others.